# How to properly compare strings in c++?

Tags: c++

Good night to everyone!

I am trying to compare 2 strings in c++, using the .compare() function. However, the result i see is not what is expected from this function. Take a look please.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class game 
{

    private:

    char mtx [2][2];
    int i = 0, j = 0, a = 0;
    std::string matrix1;
    std::string xis = "xx";

    public:
        game();
        char winner();
};
game::game()
{
    for(i = 0; i<2; i++)
                     {
        for (j = 0; j<2; j++)
        {
             mtx [i][j] = 'x';
        }
}

char game::winner()
{
    i = j = 0;
    for (j=0; j<2; j++)
    {
        matrix1 = mtx [0][j];  //string recieve the first line of the matrix.
    }

    a = xis.compare(matrix1);
    cout << a<<endl;
}

int main(void) {
    velha game;
    velha.winner;
}
```

When I compile the program the a value printed is **neither a '0' nor any other integers**. It prints #85.

> **Notes:** I've also tried to use `<string.h>` and `strncmp()` using a char array instead of std:: string but with no success.
>   I was trying to create a game class and I did not put here the other methods because they are not relevant). (also, I use Linux Mint to code)

Can anyone help me please in this context?

Comment: You can just use `string1 == string2` to compare to strings. This is implemented with operator overloading (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/operator-overloading-c/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `string compare` and even `strcmp` the value returned will be the lexicographical comparison of the two strings. The following are the values you should see:

> **negative** if `*this` appears before the character sequence specified by the argument in lexicographical order
>   **0** if `*this` and the character sequence specified are equivalent
>   **positive** if `*this` appears after the character sequence specified by the argument in lexicographical order

If you are looking to get the first column of your matrix, do a string comparison on, you would want to do something like:

```
for(int col = 0; col < 2; col++) {
    matrix1.push_back(mtx[0][col]); // This appends that character to the end of your string
}
```

If you are looking to get the rows you can just do the following:

```
matrix1 = mtx[0];
// To ensure you have a null terminated string
// Otherwise you will have garbage.
matrix1.replace(matrix1.begin() + 2, matrix1.end(), 1, "\0");
```

I have ran through the test with comparing that the matrix contains "xx" and ended up receiving 0. However a much easier comparison is to us `operator ==` to simply return a `true` or `false` value.

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(void) {
    std::string first, second;

    std::cout << "First String: ";
    getline(std::cin, first);

    std::cout << "Second Line: ";
    getline(std::cin, second);

    if (first == second)
        std::cout << "Same strings.";
    else 
        std::cout << "Different strings.";

    return 0;
}
```

**Explanation:** Just taken two strings from the user and matches straightforward without using any much complexity, just used a conditional operation.

Comment: Tip: Try to avoid `using namespace std` and just leave the prefix. This helps avoid conflict with user defined classes, structures and functions.

Comment: Yeah, in case he needs to make bigger programs, then they need. Just for clarification, I provided.

Comment: Not sure what that explanation means. The `std::` prefix helps with learning because it's instantly obvious where to go for documentation. It seems annoying at first but you get used to it.

Comment: Once you're used to it it's easier to read as those symbols help differentiate things better, especially once you start using Boost and other namespaced libraries.